# how to recover file and folder permission?

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod

I made this mistake at the /usr directory

```
sudo chmod -R 777 bin
```

The next time i used sudo, it gives me this prompt:

```
sudo must be setuid root
```

What I did is copy and replaced this sudo thinking it would recover its default permission. Now the sudo command prompts this :

```
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

HELP. I cant change the permission of sudo already. pexec did nothing as well.

Comment: You can try to boot from an Live CD and use the root account to restore the permissions...

Comment: Try the command `sudo -i`, type your password, and then try to change permissions.